# ASSEMBLY get number input

Tags: assembly, input, x86, numbers, dos

I have some problems, I am new to assembly, but have task to read two numbers from keybord input
for example [156,59].

I know that I can get one digit keyboard using this code:

```
    mov ah, 1h 
    int 21h 
    mov dl, al 
    mov ah, 2h 
    int 21h
```

But I have no idea how to read two numbers.
maybe someone can help me.

```
EDIT:

    marca db 'A$'
...
    READING:
    mov ah,1 
    int 21h
    mov text[bx+di] , Al
    inc di
    cmp Al , 13 
    JNE READING
    mov text[bx+di] , '$'
...
```

I made some function, but problem is that I cannot output `text`using function:

```
mov dx, OFFSET text
mov ah,09h   
int 21h
```

just returns nothing. where is problem?

Comment: Read a digit multiple times until you get a delimiter of your choice.

Comment: You'll get better answers, if you post a whole program which a helper can easily copy&paste&compile&run&analyze. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Please tell additionally the assembler you're using (TASM or MASM or NASM or ...).

Comment: Shouldn't you also change that last *marca db 'A$'* to *text  db 'A$'* or even *text db '?????'* ?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use this code in a loop, until the user presses enter (10 or 13) or the "]" char. Cause we don't know, how many chars the user will enter, you have to save the inputs in a variable with enough space.
Another possibility is to call the dos readLine function (int 21h/ah=0ah), which read a hole line, until the user presses enter.